# How to find the dates in multiple categories by different conditions in Presto Sql?

Tags: sql, presto

1. I need to find dates based on building. In each building, milestone Id are categorized by Milestone type, the milestone Ids have their matching Date. The date in the category of Breakground, Energization  should be the min(date). In the category of  PR, the date should be greater than today, but it should also  be the date closest to today ( That means several dates greater than today in this category)
2. I also need to find dates based on Site. The dates in the category of  Breakground, Energization should be min (date) based on site, while the date for PR should be the date greater than today but should be the date closest to today based on Site.
   How to write the SQL in Presto? Thank you.

please see the screenshot here.

[information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYjnh.png)

Comment: Hi, most questions like this get downbvoted because it is asking someone to do your work for you. If you try to solve the problem and provide your relevant code people will be more inclined to try help

Comment: I didn't intend to ask people to do my work. This is my first time to post question here. I followed  most of the questions here, which they didn't provide any code. I provided the screenshot (information) here. What I want is to get suggestion and hint how to write sql based on the screenshot.